# Can't limit length of input with ado.net

Tags: c#, ado.net

Trying to limit maximum length of input but can't. So if input length is 10, code does not limits to three. What is my mistake?

Here is code:

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

async void FillTable()
{
    string connectionString = "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=adonetdb;Trusted_Connection=True;";

   Console.WriteLine("Enter name:");
   string name = Console.ReadLine();

   Console.WriteLine("Enter age:");
   int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

   string sqlExpression = $"USE adonetdb; INSERT INTO Users (Name, Age) VALUES ('{name}', {age})";
   using SqlConnection connection = new(connectionString);
   await connection.OpenAsync();
   SqlCommand command = new(sqlExpression, connection);
   command.Parameters.Add("@name", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 3).Value = name;
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", age);
   int number = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
   Console.WriteLine("Finish");
}

FillTable();

Console.Read();
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you haven't used the parameter at all. Try instead:

```cs
const string sqlExpression = "USE adonetdb; INSERT INTO Users (Name, Age) VALUES (@name, @age)";
```

This will also solve SQL injection and i18n/l10n problems.

As a side note: spending your time messing with the ADO.NET API isn't a great use of your time; tools like Dapper will do all of this for you, correctly:

```cs
using SqlConnection connection = new(connectionString);
await connection.ExecuteAsync(sqlExpression, new { name, age }); // job done
```